# CRITICAL_SECTION occurs deadlock when using DuplicateOutput

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, directx-11, critical-section

I'm writing the C++/CLI program with IDXGIOutputDuplication.

I want to get the image from multiple threads, so I used CriticalSection. But, the code that includes "AcquireNextFrame()" and "ReleaseFrame()", thread was deadlocked.

If the UpdateDesktopImage() was deleted from the program, deadlocked will not occur. Those funcions calls from .NET Framework thread(System.Threading.Thread).  I would like to know this cause and solution.

```
HRESULT DesktopDupli::Initialize(int dispno, IDXGIAdapter *adapter, IDXGIOutput *output)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    IDXGIOutput1 *dxgi_op1 = NULL;

    DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC desc_op;
    hr = output->GetDesc(&desc_op);
    sw = desc_op.DesktopCoordinates.right - desc_op.DesktopCoordinates.left;
    sh = desc_op.DesktopCoordinates.bottom - desc_op.DesktopCoordinates.top;

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL FeatureLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1
    };
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL level;
    UINT levels = ARRAYSIZE(FeatureLevels);

    hr = D3D11CreateDevice(adapter, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN,
        NULL, 0, FeatureLevels, levels,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &device, &level, &context);
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto EXIT;

    hr = output->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIOutput1), (void**)&dxgi_op1);
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto EXIT;

    hr = dxgi_op1->DuplicateOutput(device, &dupli);
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto EXIT;

    this->dispno = dispno;

    pixelbufLen = sh * sw * 4;
    pixelbuf1 = new BYTE[pixelbufLen];

EXIT:
    RELEASE(dxgi_op1);

    return hr;
}

void DesktopDupli::Remove()
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&csec);

    // delete some buffer
    if (pixelbuf){
        delete[]pixelbuf;
        pixelbuf = NULL;
    }

    LeaveCriticalSection(&csec);
}

HRESULT DesktopDupli::UpdateDesktopImage()
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&csec);

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IDXGIResource* res = NULL;
    ID3D11Texture2D *deskimage = NULL;

    DWORD c = GetTickCount();
    if (c >= lastUpdate && c < lastUpdate + 10) goto EXIT;
    lastUpdate = c;

    if (!dupli/*<-IDXGIOutputDuplication */) {
        hr = E_POINTER;
        goto EXIT;
    }

    dupli->ReleaseFrame();
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto EXIT;
    hr = dupli->AcquireNextFrame(500, &frameinfo, &res);
    if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
        hr = S_OK;
        goto EXIT;
    } else if (FAILED(hr)){
        goto EXIT;
    }

    hr = res->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&deskimage);
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto EXIT;
    if (frameinfo.AccumulatedFrames == 0) {
        dupli->ReleaseFrame();
    }else {
        hr = SetPixel(deskimage); //CopySubresourceRegion
    }

EXIT:
    RELEASE(deskimage);
    RELEASE(res);

    LeaveCriticalSection(&csec);
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: If these are the only two functions where you use csec as your lock object, then I suspect UpdateDesktopImage calls Remove somewhere (ReleaseFrame?) causing the problem

Comment: Can you see where it's deadlocked using the debugger?

Comment: @o_weisman: a thread is allowed to enter a critical section lock multiple times once it has obtained the lock. Once the thread has the lock, subsequent calls to EnterCriticalSection() succeed without blocking. Calls to EnterCriticalSection() and LeaveCriticalSection() must be balanced to ensure the thread gives up the lock. The only way a deadlock can occur in the code shown is if the two functions are being called in separate threads, where UpdateDesktopImage() has the lock and does something that waits on the Remove() thread, which is waiting for UpdateDesktopImage() to release the lock.

Answer (score 0):

in:

```
hr = res->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&deskimage);
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto EXIT;
```

you forget to `dupli->ReleaseFrame()` before `EXIT`